# :before pseudo is obscuring text on 2 lines

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I have a :before pseudo which creates an underline on section titles see below:

```
.c-welcome__title > span:before {
    background: #98b680;
    content: "";
    height: 0.4rem;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%);
    top: 3.5rem
    width: 15rem;
}
```

this works fine when my titles are short, however when they're long and viewing from a mobile the line doesn't sit underneath the whole sentence instead it appears in the middle.

[image of the underline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJbF2.png)

HTML:

```
<h1 class="c-welcome__title">
  <span>Welcome to Sarahs store&nbsp;Welcome to Sarahs store</span>
</h1>

<p>This is somewhere you can introduce your brand and shout about how awesome your products are.</p>
```

CSS:

```
.c-welcome__title {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.c-welcome__title > span {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-bottom: 2.6rem;
}
```

Comment: Instead of placing the line from the top (`top: 3.5rem`) use bottom

Comment: I tried that, it didn't move it a significant amount unfortunately.

Comment: ... or use `::after` instead, and leave it in normal flow to begin with.

Comment: I tried that too and I also had no luck :-(

Comment: don't simply replace top with bottom, but also the value, use `bottom:0` and start increasing until you get what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't make the pseudo element absolute, just make it `display:block` and center it using `margin: 0 auto`. See code snippet.

```css
.c-welcome__title {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
.c-welcome__title > span {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-bottom: 2.6rem;
}
.c-welcome__title > span::after {
    background: #98b680;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 15rem;
    margin: 10px auto;
    height: 5px;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="c-welcome__title">
  <span>Welcome to Sarahs store&nbsp;Welcome to Sarahs store</span>
</h1>

<p>This is somewhere you can introduce your brand and shout about how awesome your products are.</p>
```